How to make a wrapper that takes one async function and returns another async function in Rust?
There is a common pattern in functional programming, when you take a function, use it and return another function (often with the same signature).
In python this pattern is so common, than it uses a specific decorator @ syntax.
I'm trying to implement this approach in rust, but fail with non-trivial examples.
Thanks for this answer, this trivial synchronous example works:
fn wrapper<T, V, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> V where
    F: Fn(T) -> V {
    move |x| f(x)
}

fn my_func_1(x: u16) -> u16 {
    x * 2
}

fn my_func_2(x: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    x.iter().sum()
}

fn main() {
    let res = wrapper(my_func_1)(42);
    let res = wrapper(my_func_2)(vec![1,2,3]);
}

But things become messy in async context!
I failed to implement the same functionality in this case.
But, thanks to this answer, I made this trivial solution:
use std::future::Future;

fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> Fut where
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output=V> {
    f
}

async fn my_func_1(x: u16) -> u16 {
    x * 2
}

async fn my_func_2(x: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    x.iter().sum()
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let res = wrapper(my_func_1)(42).await;
    println!("my_func_1: res = {:?}", res);
    let res = wrapper(my_func_2)(vec![1,2,3]).await;
    println!("my_func_2: res = {:?}", res);
}

Compared with synchronous implementation in async wrapper I can't create a new function to return.
Something like this:
fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> Fut where
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output=V> {
    move |x| async { f(x) }
}

fails with error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:14
  |
4 | fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> Fut where
  |                     --- expected this type parameter
...
7 |     move |x| async { f(x) }
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `Fut`, found `async` block
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `Fut`
              found `async` block `{async block@src/main.rs:7:14: 7:28}`
  = help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `Fut`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `rust_test` (bin "rust_test") due to 1 previous error


Any suggestions!?

Please post the full error from cargo check, not your IDE.

-> impl Fn(T) -> Fut means a function that given a T returns Fut; note Fut is a fixed type here. It's not clear to me if you want this to remain this way (in which case the error makes sense, since you are not returning a Fut from the closure), or if you intent this to be a different future than Fut that happens to also output a V and may even use F in doing so.

What you actually want is something like -> impl Fn(T) -> impl Future<Output = V> but this syntax is (currently) disallowed.

You're wrapping a Future in another async block, so this function:
fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> ?
where
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = V>,
{
    move |x| async { f(x) }
}

would need to be called with two awaits:
let res = wrapper(my_func_1)(42).await.await;

This is probably not what you want. You either want the closure to return the Future directly:
fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> Fut
where
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = V>,
{
    move |x| f(x)
}

or you want to await the Future and return a new Future type. Unfortunately, you need another trait to express this.
fn wrapper<T, V, F, Fut>(f: F) -> impl FutureFn<T, Fut: Future<Output = V>>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = V>,
{
    |x| async move { f(x).await }
}

trait FutureFn<T>: FnOnce(T) -> Self::Fut {
    type Fut: Future;
}

impl<F, Fut, T> FutureFn<T> for F
where
    F: FnOnce(T) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future,
{
    type Fut = Fut;
}

Check out Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument for more about this. Note that when T includes a lifetime, this only works when you pass an async function item into wrapper and not a closure.

@cdhowie I definitely copied the wrong thing there, it should just return Fut

Ah, that does make more sense!
